# Magento 2 cached image error, Warning: getimagesize()

Tags: cache, product-images, magento2

I recently pulled the latest version of Magento 2 and now all my product & catgeory pages display a version of the following error, which basically says that the image cannot be found to get the dimensions.

```
Warning: getimagesize(/Users/adammoss/projects/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/240x300/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/m/y/freddy.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/adammoss/PhpstormProjects/magento2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 936
```

I have cleared the main cache, var/generation, images cache etc but nothing seems to help. The cache directory is missing from the pub/media/catalog/product directory.

[image]

Version: 2.0.0.0-dev35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.
I already [reported](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1647) it yesterday

Comment: Thanks, I was convinced I had some separate caching/permissions issue.